# Definition of the weak solution to the Dirichlet boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open. The dirichlet problem is given by

> \begin{align}
> -\Delta u &= f \text{ on } \Omega \\
> u&=0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega
> \end{align}

for a function $f \in L^2(\Omega)$. When defining the weak solution I always saw that it was assumed that $\Omega$ is bounded and then the weak solution was defined as a function $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that
$$\int \langle \nabla u, \nabla w \rangle = \int f w \text{ for all } w \in H^1_0(\Omega).$$

But does this definition still hold or even make sense if we do not assume that $\Omega$ is bounded, just that it is open?

Comment: I think you mean $\int \nabla u \nabla w = \int fw$.

Comment: oh yes thank you. But does it make sense to allow $\Omega$ to not be bounded?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this definition can still be used for unbounded domains. For example, it appears in the paper [*Dirichlet problem for a linear elliptic equation in unbounded domains with $L^2$-boundary data*](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=RSMUP_1984__71__287_0) by Chabrowski (this is just one of search results).

One is likely to find that some *theorems* about weak solutions either no longer hold, or require more difficult proof; which is probably why the assumption of boundedness is made.